# Android HttpUrlConnection does not work

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

I made web site by using my localhost and it has some values and button.
If someone access to url (for example `http://myhost/?status2=0`), value is change.

I want to this action in Android, so I used `HttpURLConnection` but it doesn't work.

If I access to URL by using Intent (`ACTION_VIEW`, `Uri.parse("http...")`) in Android, it works well.

But I access to URL by using `HttpURLConnection`, it doesn't work. I don't know what is wrong. Please help me.

This is code in Android app. I already checked manifests.

```
try{
    URL url = new URL("http://myhost/?status2=0");

    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); 
    conn.setUseCaches(false);
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setDoInput(true);
    conn.setDoOutput(true);

} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: im not sure but i think if you want to use "HttpURLConnection" your url should contain "www". try it and check if it works?

Comment: You can use OkHttp 3rd party library. It's preferred by many over the HttpURLConnection .

Answer (score 0):

Ok you can use `Retrofit` or `OkHttp` but in `HttpUrlConnection` try like that :

```
    public  void refreshToken(String url,String refresh,String cid,String csecret) throws IOException {
        URL refreshUrl = new URL(url + "token");
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) refreshUrl.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        urlConnection.setUseCaches(false);
        String urlParameters = "grant_type=refresh_token&client_id=" + cid + "&client_secret=" + csecret + "&refresh_token=" + refresh;
        // Send post request
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
        wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();
        int responseCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
        //this is my Pojo class . I am converting response to Pojo with Gson
        RefreshTokenResult refreshTokenResult = new RefreshTokenResult();
        if (responseCode == 200) {

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(inputLine);
            }
            in.close();
            // JSONObject obj=new JSONObject(response.toString());
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            refreshTokenResult = gson.fromJson(response.toString(), RefreshTokenResult.class);
            //handle new token ...
            mLoginPrefsEditor = mLoginPreferences.edit();
            mLoginPrefsEditor.commit();
            mLoginPrefsEditor.putString(mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.pref_accesstoken), "Bearer " + refreshTokenResult.getAccessToken());
            mLoginPrefsEditor.putString(mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.pref_refreshtoken), refreshTokenResult.getRefreshToken());
            mLoginPrefsEditor.commit();
        }   
}
```

In my other requests i am using `OkHttp` backed `Retrofit` , but in refresh token - refresh token is a critical process for me - i am using `HttpUrlConnection` .

When i use `OkHttp` or `Retrofit` in refresh token method sometimes it wont going correct.

And i got this : sometimes you need to use basic handshake method with `HttpUrlConnection`.